# WPF event that triggers after the mouse stops moving

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing a WPF application.
I want to trigger an event once the mouse stops moving.

This is how I tried to do it. I created a timer which counts down to 5 seconds. This timer is "reset" every time the mouse moves.
This idea is that the moment the mouse stops moving, the timer stops being reset, and counts down from 5 to zero, and then calls the tick event handler, which displays a message box.

Well, it doesn't work as expected, and it floods me with alert messages. What am I doing wrong?

```
DispatcherTimer timer;

private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Mouse stopped moving");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `unhook` the `event` before hooking it again like this -

```
private void poc_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (timer != null)
   {
      timer.Tick-= timer_Tick;
   }
   timer = new DispatcherTimer();
   timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
   timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
   timer.Start();
}
```

**Explanation**

What you doing is whenever a mouse moves, you create a new instance of DispatcherTimer and hook Tick event to it without `unhooking the event for previous instance`. Hence, you see flooded messages once timer stops for all the instances.

Also, you should unhook it otherwise previous instance won't be `garbage collected` since they are still `strongly referenced`.

Answer (score 8):

It is not necessary to create a new timer on every MouseMove event. Just stop and restart it. And also make sure that it is stopped in the Tick handler, since it should be fired only once.

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("Mouse stopped moving");
}

private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Start();
}
```