# How to trigger a event when the mouse don't move?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouse

How can I trigger an event if the mouse don't move, in a WPF application using C#?

Comment: use a timer and tick for the mouse position, I don't think there is an event

Comment: mouse don't move for how long?

Comment: Track it when it *is* moving, have some kind of a stamp that represents the time the mouse was last moved, and then if that goes over a certain threshold, raise an event?

Comment: How often do you want the event to fire, 'when', the mouse doesn't move?

Comment: yeah, put a timer that restart every time the mouse move, on the tick event of the timer launch your custome event, this way you can decide how much time the mouse have to be motionless before firing the event

Comment: I believe your question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216890/wpf-event-that-triggers-after-the-mouse-stops-moving

Comment: I want the event to fire just once when the mouse doesn't move that's why i don't use a timer and tick. Something like the mouse move event.

Comment: you just stop the timer when its happened once, my mouse hasn't moved while I've been writing this comment, would this trigger your event?

Comment: If I set the timer interval to 3 sec and i move my mouse after 3 sec the event is triggered even if i still move my mouse that's why i don't use timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I'd add a pseudo code version of how to use a timer (not got visual studio on this computer can update later).

```
private Point lastPos;
public Timer_tick(s,e)
{
    if(mousePosition != lastPos)
    {
       MouseHasntMoved();
       timer.Stop();
    }
}
public override MouseMove(s,e)
{
    timer.Reset();
    lastPos = mousePosition;
}
public void MouseHasntMoved()
{
//Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i found a simpler answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216890/wpf-event-that-triggers-after-the-mouse-stops-movinm) .